# Centering image acting as an "popup" both horizontally AND vertically

Tags: html, css

I am working on an responsive mobile website with a max width of 640px.

I have an picture of 640 x 1060 I want to use a "popup".

Since I already have an entire website with overlays etc the z-index needs to be 7 to overal everything.

I want padding around the sides and an auto heigh depending on the device's resolution.
So for example either:

```
Padding-left: 10px 
Padding-right-10px
```

or

```
width: 95%
```

This while the height auto adjusts to keep aspect ratio.
All this while keeping the image both horizontal and vertically centered. (In the middle of the screen)

The position needs to be `fixed` as I don't want the used to be able to scroll "past" the image, but rather, in their face and make them close it.

Answer (score -1):

you can try:

```
 position:fixed;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 transform: translate (-50%,-50%)
```

Comment: I want the position to be fixed and on top of everything (z index 7)

Comment: you can use the same values with `fixed` , z-index shouldn'y have any effect on centering

Comment: what do you mean with  "cleary the container will also have to be centered" ?

Comment: that was if it was `position:relative` (relative to it's parent..) but with `fixed` the positioning is always relative to window so don't worry about that, I'll edit answer. Does the code work?